# Submitted InfoPath forms cannot be opened in browser

Tags: 2013, infopath, browser-compatibility

After attempting to solve a minor glitch with security signatures, any form I submit using the InfoPath Form Filler cannot be opened in the browser, even after removing all the signatures. I can submit a form using the same template online and it works correctly but if I use the InfoPath Form Filler it forces me to download the submitted form as an xml file. Any one got any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What security signature glitch did you resolve and in which fashion? Could your solution urn have changed in the template? Have you verified that necessary ActiveX controls are used by the browser and the client machine has necessary ProgID associations and COM class registrations?